# Convergence/divergence of the sequence $( \frac{2n^3 - 5n + 2}{3n^3 + 8n +3} )_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have been working on this problem and would love some detailed help on it.

> Decide whether the following sequence converges or diverges. Prove your answer
>   using the definition of convergence.
>   $$ c_n=\frac{2n^3 - 5n + 2}{3n^3 + 8n +3}$$

Now I do believe that the sequence converges to $2/3$. Now to prove this we would need to show that the difference between the sequence $c_n$ and its limit $L$ (in this case $2/3$) is very smaller than our error or $\epsilon$

$$\left|\frac{2n^3 - 5n + 2}{3n^3 + 8n +3} - \frac23\right|<\epsilon$$

After reducing this I can find the number $N$ that I am looking for and say that the sequence converges if the number $n$ that we choose is strictly greater than $N$ correct? Unfortunately, I am not sure on how to reduce this absolute value and help would be greatly appreciated!

The more detailed the help the better.

Comment: i don't understand your question, are you trying to find an expression for an explicit $N$ for very $\epsilon>0$?

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, have you tried subtracting the two fractions to get a single fraction?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. However, I understand that the limit is $2/3$ but to write a formal proof of this don't we have to use the definition of a limit and find an epsilon and $N$ ?

Comment: Check my second answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little manipulation shows that

$$\left|\frac{2n^3 - 5n + 2}{3n^3 + 8n +3} - \frac{2}{3}\right|=\left|\frac{-31n}{3(3n^3+8n+3)}\right|.\tag{$1$}$$

The expression on the right of $(1)$ is pleasantly simple. Thank you, problem setter! For positive $n$, the denominator is greater than $9n^3$.  So for positive $n$, the expression on the right of $(1)$ is clearly between $0$ and $\dfrac{31n}{9n^3}$. which is $\dfrac{31}{9n^2}$.

Suppose that we are given an $\epsilon \gt 0$. Then if $\dfrac{31}{9n^2}\lt \epsilon$, the expression on the left of $(1)$ will be less than $\epsilon$.

Now $\dfrac{31}{9n^2}\lt \epsilon$ precisely if $n\gt \sqrt{31/(9\epsilon)}$.

So if we pick $N$ as, for example, the smallest integer which is greater than 
$\sqrt{31/(9\epsilon)}$, then for any $n\gt N$, we will have 
$$\left|\frac{2n^3 - 5n + 2}{3n^3 + 8n +3} - \frac{2}{3}\right|\lt \epsilon.$$

That is precisely what we needed to do to show that the limit is $\dfrac{2}{3}$ from the *definition* of limit, that is, using an "$\epsilon$-$N$" analysis. We have shown that given any $\epsilon\gt 0$, we can produce an $N=N(\epsilon)$ such that if $n\gt N$, then the expression on the left of $(1)$ is $\lt \epsilon$.

Comment: We just gave basically the same answer. I think there's just a little mistake in your first equation. The denominator on the right hand side must be multiplied by 3.

Comment: Thanks, I do have trouble with common denominators.

Comment: Thank you very much appreciated it!

Comment: You are welcome. This problem was technically simple, since the inequalities were clear. If the denominator had been, say, $3n^3-20n^2-12n+1$, things get more complicated, since the denominator is no longer bigger than $3n^3$. Solving a problem by $\epsilon$-$N$ can be unpleasant. That's why you will soon have shortcut theorems. It is just like derivatives. Kind of hard to do from the definition, but soon one has rules (therems). And we need to go back to the definition only when we meet a new *kind* of situation.

Answer (score 2):

$$\left|\frac{2n^3 - 5n + 2}{3n^3 + 8n +3} - \frac23\right|<\epsilon \qquad(1)$$
is equivalent to

$$ \frac{31n}{9n^3+24n+9} <\epsilon$$

Since

$$\frac{31n}{9n^3+24n+9} \lt \frac{31n}{9n^3} = \frac{31}{9n^2}$$

we need an integer $N$ that satisfies

$$N \gt \sqrt{\frac{31}{9\epsilon}}$$

to guarantee that inequality (1) is satisfied for $n\ge N$.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you simply divide the numerator and the denominator by $n^3$ you get

$$\frac{2-\frac{5}{n^2}+\frac{2}{n^3}}{3+\frac{8}{n^2}+3\frac{3}{n^3}}$$

All the terms proportional to $\frac{1}{n^2}$ and $\frac{1}{n^3}$ converge to zero. So the limiting value is indeed $\frac{2}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \frac{2n^3-5n+2}{3n^3+8n+3}=\frac{2-\frac{5}{n^2}+\frac{2}{n^3}}{3+\frac{8}{n^2}+\frac{3}{n^3}}$

Now show that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}(2-\frac{5}{n^2}+\frac{2}{n^3})=2$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}(3+\frac{8}{n^2}+\frac{3}{n^3})=3$ (fact 1)

This would imply $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2n^3-5n+2}{3n^3+8n+3}=\frac{\lim_{n\to \infty}(2-\frac{5}{n^2}+\frac{2}{n^3})}{\lim_{n\to \infty}(3+\frac{8}{n^2}+\frac{3}{n^3})}=2/3$

Fact 1 can easily be proved using the fact $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2}=\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{1}{n^3}=0$